# Make imagettftext recognice HEX colors

Tags: php, hex, gd

Simple question, I searched over there and didnt found a way to make this.

I have a string (variable one) which can be like this:

```
#FF9900Hel#FFFFFFlo
```

I need a way to make the imagettftext function recognice those colors and draw the text using those colors. For example, in the example I mentioned before, the text should be: in red: Hel and in white:lo. I hope I explained well what I mean.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's absolutely nothing in `imagettftext` that would make it do that. You'll have to do this yourself, by putting it as two separate text parts with two different colors into the image, aligning them with some math.

Comment: Well i understand that. Im new in this. Is there any function which could convert those HEX colors into an actual variable I could use for imagettftext or I should make my own function for that too?

Comment: If you understand that, than your question was worded very differently. Best describe what specific problem you have in implementing the process described above.

Comment: Well if I asked the question is because maybe there was an easier way than making my own function, since I doubt if I will be able to do it with my low knowledge. Now I know theres not an easier way I will give a try in making a function for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You not only need to recognize colors, you also need to *align* the strings. This is not automatic as it is in HTML.

I would do this by first splitting the string into its components parts:

```
// Split the text using hex colors as strings:
$hex     = '[0-9a-fA-F]'; // Capital hex should be supported

$colorex = "(#{$hex}{$hex}{$hex}{$hex}{$hex}{$hex})";
// or also $colorex = "(#{$hex}{6})";

$parts = preg_split ("/{$colorex}/", $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

// Then you would iterate through the parts:

$color = imageColorAllocate($gd, 0, 0, 0); // Default is black
foreach($parts as $part)
{
    // Scan the hex value
    if (preg_match("/^{$colorex}\$/", $part, $gregs))
    {
        sscanf($gregs[1], "#%02x%02x%02x", &$r, &$g, &$b);
        $color = imageColorAllocate($gd, $r, $g, $b);
        continue;
    }
    // IMPROVEMENT: if count(explode("\n", $part)) > 1, $y += $height, $x = 0
    // to indicate "go to next line". So this would appear on two lines:
    //     #012345Hel#ff7700lo,
    //     #443212World 
    // Next section will be repeated for each item
    // in the exploded string.
    //! $subparts = explode("\n", $part);
    //! foreach($subparts as $part)
    //! { // We have overwritten $part

    // Here $part is printed as string at position $x, $y
    // Ask GD to calculate string width
    // with http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php
    // Calculations with $angle != 0 is a bit more difficult, entails trigonometric
    // evaluation of $w and $h.
    $bbox = imagettfbbox ($size, $angle, $fontfile, $part);
    $w    = $bbox[4] - $bbox[0];  // 0,1 is lower left corner
    $h    = $bbox[5] - $bbox[1];  // 4,5 is upper right
    imagettftext ($gd, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $color, $fontfile, $part);
    // Increment $x position by $w
    $x += $w;

    //!     if (count($subparts) > 1)
    //!     {
    //!         $x = 0; $y += $h;
    //!     }
    //! }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have to parse out the colors and corresponding strings, allocate GD color resources for each unique color, and make separate calls to `imagettftext` adjusting your `x` and `y` coordinates as needed.

The `imagettxtext` function can not and will not do this for you.

Look into [imageftbbox](http://php.net/imageftbbox) because you will need this function in order to calculate the bounding box for each slice of text which is required for properly placing the next chunk of text that is in a different color.

Here is a function for converting HTML colors to hex triplets that you can pass to [imagecolorallocate](http://php.net/imagecolorallocate).

```
function htmlColorToHex($color) {
    if (substr($color, 0, 1) == '#') {
        $color = substr($color, 1);
    }

    if (strlen($color) == 3) {
        $red   = str_repeat(substr($color, 0, 1), 2);
        $green = str_repeat(substr($color, 1, 1), 2);
        $blue  = str_repeat(substr($color, 2, 1), 2);
    } else {
        $red   = substr($color, 0, 2);
        $green = substr($color, 2, 2);
        $blue  = substr($color, 4, 2);
    }

    $hex = array('r' => hexdec($red),
                 'g' => hexdec($green),
                 'b' => hexdec($blue));

    return $hex;
}
```

The most complicated part of what you want to do is going to be correctly calculating the coordinates for each portion of text.